# Button pressed js overlay function

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

So, I have a js script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changePh").click(function() {
        $("changebox").overlay().load();
    \});

    $("#changebox").overlay({
        top: 260,
                mask: {
            color: '#fff',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.5
            },
            closeOnClick: false,
            load: true
        });
        });
</script>
```

and i wanted that overlay appears after that i pressed the button, insted now it's appears
immediately i load the page

I have also a button with id="changePh" and a form with id="changebox"

Who can help me...

Comment: remove the overlay from the document.ready function...

Comment: Changing `load: true` to `load: false` might do it.

Comment: just put the overlay function inside the click.You are assigning the overlay function directly when you use $('#changebox').overlay({});

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `overlay` function inside `click` function:

```
$("#changePh").click(function() {
    $("#changebox").overlay().load();
    $("#changebox").overlay({
        top: 260,
        mask: {
            color: '#fff',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        closeOnClick: false,
        load: true
    });
});
```

Btw, you're missing `#` inside `$("#changebox")` and redundant `\` before closing `})` of your `click` function.